# bootstrap dropdown text customize css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to HTML and CSS and I am looking for a best/correct way to customize my bootstrap component. I need to change the bootstrap drown down menu to be like this :

[image]

What I have done so far is this:

http://www.bootply.com/5DztqTZYIe

My problem is I don't know how should I tackle the changing drop-down text menu to be something like the image (with little triangle on top-right corner and the selected menu with check mark).

I appreciate any help.

The HTML Code:

```
<div class="btn-group " uib-dropdown="" is-open="status.isopen">
     <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary drop" ng-disabled="disabled" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <div class="preCaretDiv"><div class="preCaretText">Relative Difference </div> <div class="caretCircle"><span class="caret"></span></div></div>
     </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">    
    <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.btn.drop {
  background: #e1e6e4;
  border-color: #e1e6e4;
  color: #25373e;

}

.caretCircle {
      float:right;
      background-color:white;
      border-radius:50%;
      height:1em;
      width:1em;  
      margin-top:.2em;
      margin-left:.25em;
      color:#25373e;

  }

.caretCircle .caret {
  padding-bottom:.5em;      
  border-top-width:.3em;
  border-right-width:.3em;
  border-left-width:.3em;
}

.preCaretText {
  float:left;
}

.preCaretDiv
{
  display: inline-flex;
}

 .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    background-color: #25373e;
    color:#ffffff;
  }

.btn.drop:focus, .btn.drop:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn{
  background: #b2babb !important;
  border-color: #b2babb !important;
  color: #25373e !important;
  .caretCircle {
    background-color:#25373e !important;
    color:#00e0b8 !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this CSS.

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #25373e;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.open>.dropdown-menu:after, 
.open>.dropdown-menu:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.open>.dropdown-menu:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #25373e;
    border-width: 8px;
    right: 5%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.open>.dropdown-menu:before {
    border-color: rgba(113, 158, 206, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #25373e;
    border-width: 9px;
    right: 5%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Example [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/it0XVfviGe)

### Edit

To make the checkmark work, we need a bit of javascript and a little more CSS

Our javascript:

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").click(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
  $("ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").removeClass("option-selected");
  $(e.target).addClass("option-selected");
});
```

And our extra CSS:

```
.option-selected:after {
    content: '✔';
    color: #27f1ce;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    float:right;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1e2c32;
}
```

Example [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/11KF8mKkGf).

If you include font-awesome, you can get a better check mark by using this CSS instead.

```
.option-selected:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c";
    color: #27f1ce;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    float:right;
}
```

### Edit 3

[Final bootply](http://www.bootply.com/cMQo8dGUOu). This one contains some other styling and makes it a bit more similar to the original.

My version:

[image: Style]

Comment: it's very nice but what about the check on a selected item?

Comment: Currently looking into that one. I missed it in the original request.

Comment: It may be a bit more cumbersome as you're using lists instead of a true dropdown, so some javascript trickery may be needed.

Comment: Also another quick question as you can see in my question I want to change the color when I hover over any option, right now it shows white background how can I change that?

Comment: I promise that is my last question,  is there any way and can change the background color of selected option beside showing the check mark? when I add background color in .option-selected:after it only changes the background color of check mark. I want to have different background for hovered and selected. thanks in advance. you helped a lot.

Comment: [Here you go](http://www.bootply.com/otJV5QmxCn). I set it to the color: `#0055bb`. You can simply change this to whatever color you wish. I also made the css a bit closer to the original.

Comment: [Last update I swear](http://www.bootply.com/cMQo8dGUOu). This will keep the text from overflowing onto the second line (mostly).

Answer (score -2):

You could see this example, I hope you serve
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html